# How to close a chain when the pin was broken

Tags: shimano, chain

I was changing the chain on a bike with a Shimano gear shifter and when I was trying to push the pin in it broke off after only getting the front section in.

How can I recover and attach the chain?

[image]
[image]

Comment: There's an existing [question and answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/65800/reinforced-shimano-pin-snapped-before-connecting-chain-how-to-resolve) that deals with this very situation. TLDR, drive the 'leader' section out, try again with a replacement pin (bike shops have them). My answer explains why this is OK to do. A Shimano Quick link is also a good solution.

Comment: I just wonder how you managed to do that!

Comment: @Carel i was pushing the pin with linking tool and it snapped

Answer (score 3):

you could consider buying a quick link aka missing link from shimano, removing half a chain link (the one in which the broken off pin is located) and installing the quick link in its place. Alternatively if shortening the chain by just a bit is an option you could consider removing the chain link in which the broken off pin is located and reattaching the chain using a new pin from shimano (you can buy them separately from shimano; search for shimano chain pin).
[image]

alternatively you could try pushing the original pin which is currently inserted most of the way in using some water pump pliers and pushing the last section in using a chain tool.

Comment: Judging from the photo my bike has a different style of pin

Comment: @user1605665 the pins on quick links /master links always look different from the rest of the pins in your chain (and also look different from the closing pin that broke off in your case). I'm quite sure this would work in your case as long as you get the quick link for the correct speed chain